# Should I stick with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and upgrade kernel to 5.8 or install Ubuntu 20.10 for Ryzen 4000 series?

Tags: 20.04, amd-ryzen

I have a Lenovo Ideapad with ryzen 4300U CPU. I have read that Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS with kernel 5.4 LTS is not compatible with AMD ryzen 4000 series due to renoir integrated GPU.

Is it better to use Ubuntu 20.04.1 with upgraded kernel or AMD proprietary driver, or to use Ubuntu 20.10 with kernel 5.8 which the supports ryzen 4000 series?

Comment: I would try 20.10.

Comment: I run a 4700U on my Vivobook with kernel 5.8 works perfectly. I think with the 20.04 stock kernel it worked too

Comment: @bruh what linux distro that you use? Is it ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: @antoniushendra yes, ubuntu 20.04

Comment: It's up to you. You can install the 5.8 kernel to 20.04. It will officially come with 20.04.2. Or you can use 20.10 with the 5.8 kernel. No much difference except that 20.04 is an LTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have Asus Zenbook 14 with Ryzen 7 4700U and I had problems with touchpad and screen brightness on Ubuntu 20.04.

Ubuntu 20.10 beta works without troubles, so I think that you should use newer versions of Ubuntu but Ubuntu 20.04 with upgraded kernel should work too.

Comment: I use ubuntu 20.10 and the screen brightness is Ok

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install latest official HWE stack for Ubuntu with this command:

`sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04`

It will install the Kernel from 20.10(at that time) and will be updated automatically with apt to provide better support for newer hardware. You can read more about it on official wiki (maybe bit outdated for the kernel versions numbers there) [HWE stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

Answer (score -3):

I am using 20.10 on XMG core 15 amd (ryzen 7 4800 nvidia 1650ti). Things work nearly as expected, only it freezes sometimes (unpredictable, but often after it seems to get into powersaving mode) and often gets stuck during shutdown for some reason.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question. Try to be more specific.